# Gitlab CI error mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 7 column 11

Tags: gitlab-ci

This is my code which is producing errors at line 7 column 11, mostly at `script`. I am using windows operating system. This is my first time coding at gitlab.

```yaml
stages:
    -build
    -test
    
build:
    stage:build
    script:
        -echo "Building"
        -mkdir build
        -touch build/info.txt
    
test:
    stage:test
    script:
        -echo "Testing"
        -test -f "build/info.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can to debug by CI lint gitlab or yamllint.com.
You must put spaces after a dash and a colon in your case.

```
    stages:
     - build
     - test
        
    build:
     stage: build
     script:
     - echo "Building"
     - mkdir build
     - touch build/info.txt
        
    test:
     stage: test
     script:
     - echo "Testing"
     - test -f "build/info.txt"
```